# Set value of DependencyProperty and preserve OneWayToSource-Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependencyobject

If I have a `DependencyObject` with a `OneWayToSource` `Binding` set on one property and then try to set the DP's value again, the `Binding` is being removed.
I can not use the 'reversed' way with a direct (normal) Binding, so I have to use a OneWayToSource Binding. My question is whether there is another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me see if I understand correctly, you have something like this:

```
<SomeControl x:Name="MyControl" MyProp="{Binding Something, Mode="OneWayToSource"}".../>
```

Then, in code-behind, you try to set `MyProp` to some other value

```
MyControl.MyProp = SomethingElse;
```

And now changes to `MyProp` are not updating `Something` because binding is removed. Right?

In that case, and if you work under .NET 4.0 or above, you can use `SetCurrent`:

```
MyControl.SetCurrent(MyPropProperty, SomethingElse);
```

Comment: Great! I would never have found this. I wonder whether there is a way in other .NET versions...

Comment: Was added at 4.0. It was greatly missed till then. IIRC, there were some ways but they were messy.